# AAPT: error: attribute android:extractNativeLibs not found

Tags: android, android-studio, unity-game-engine, gradle, android-ndk

I tried to build APK from unity exported project
and then I encountered error
I need to build it using SDK version 22 (android 5.1)

the main problem is

```
Execution failed for task ':launcher:processDebugResources'
```

the detail as below

> Configure project :launcher
> WARNING: The option setting 'android.enableR8=false' is deprecated.
> It will be removed in version 5.0 of the Android Gradle plugin.
> You will no longer be able to disable R8

> Task :unityLibrary:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
> Task :launcher:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
> Task :launcher:preDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:preDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:compileDebugAidl NO-SOURCE
> Task :unityLibrary:packageDebugRenderscript NO-SOURCE
> Task :launcher:generateDebugBuildConfig UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:writeDebugAarMetadata UP-TO-DATE
> Task :launcher:compileDebugAidl NO-SOURCE
> Task :unityLibrary:compileDebugRenderscript NO-SOURCE
> Task :launcher:compileDebugRenderscript NO-SOURCE
> Task :unityLibrary:generateDebugResValues UP-TO-DATE
> Task :launcher:javaPreCompileDebug UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:generateDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
> Task :launcher:checkDebugAarMetadata UP-TO-DATE
> Task :launcher:generateDebugResValues UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:packageDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
> Task :launcher:generateDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:extractDeepLinksDebug UP-TO-DATE
> Task :launcher:mergeDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:processDebugManifest UP-TO-DATE
> Task :launcher:createDebugCompatibleScreenManifests UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:compileDebugLibraryResources UP-TO-DATE
> Task :launcher:extractDeepLinksDebug UP-TO-DATE
> Task :launcher:processDebugMainManifest UP-TO-DATE
> Task :launcher:processDebugManifest UP-TO-DATE
> Task :launcher:processDebugManifestForPackage UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:parseDebugLocalResources UP-TO-DATE
> Task :launcher:mergeDebugNativeDebugMetadata NO-SOURCE
> Task :launcher:mergeDebugShaders UP-TO-DATE
> Task :launcher:compileDebugShaders NO-SOURCE
> Task :launcher:generateDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:generateDebugRFile UP-TO-DATE
> Task :launcher:processDebugJavaRes NO-SOURCE
> Task :unityLibrary:generateDebugBuildConfig UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:javaPreCompileDebug UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:compileDebugJavaWithJavac UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:bundleLibCompileToJarDebug UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:mergeDebugShaders UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:compileDebugShaders NO-SOURCE
> Task :unityLibrary:generateDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:packageDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:processDebugJavaRes NO-SOURCE
> Task :unityLibrary:bundleLibResDebug NO-SOURCE
> Task :unityLibrary:bundleLibRuntimeToJarDebug UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:mergeDebugJniLibFolders UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:mergeDebugNativeLibs UP-TO-DATE

> Task :unityLibrary:stripDebugDebugSymbols UP-TO-DATE
> WARNING: NDK was located by using ndk.dir property. This method is deprecated and will be removed in a future release. Please use android.ndkVersion or android.ndkPath in build.gradle to specify the NDK to use. https://developer.android.com/r/studio-ui/ndk-dir
> NDK was located by using ndk.dir property. This method is deprecated and will be removed in a future release. Please use android.ndkVersion or android.ndkPath in build.gradle to specify the NDK to use. https://developer.android.com/r/studio-ui/ndk-dir

> Task :unityLibrary:copyDebugJniLibsProjectOnly UP-TO-DATE

> Task :launcher:processDebugResources FAILED
> AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"Android resource linking failed","sources":[{"file":"/Users/thedventh/Documents/Builds/[AndroidProj]AlQolam-Mathkids/launcher/build/intermediates/packaged_manifests/debug/AndroidManifest.xml","position":{"startLine":36}}],"original":"/Users/thedventh/Documents/Builds/[AndroidProj]AlQolam-Mathkids/launcher/build/intermediates/packaged_manifests/debug/AndroidManifest.xml:37: AAPT: error: attribute android:extractNativeLibs not found.\n    ","tool":"AAPT"}

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':launcher:processDebugResources'.

> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.Workers$ActionFacade
> Android resource linking failed
> /Users/thedventh/Documents/Builds/[AndroidProj]AlQolam-Mathkids/launcher/build/intermediates/packaged_manifests/debug/AndroidManifest.xml:37: AAPT: error: attribute android:extractNativeLibs not found.

- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 1s
31 actionable tasks: 1 executed, 30 up-to-date

Any help or info are appreciated
thanks you

Comment: **"Starting with AGP 4.2.0, the extractNativeLibs manifest attribute has been replaced by the DSL option useLegacyPackaging."** [source](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/application-element#extractNativeLibs). So check your `AndroidManifest.xml` for that property. If it is not included then it may be added by a library you use, contact the author of the library to update it.